# how can i find same value in list dart?

Tags: dart

i want to get StockModel which is code is "A006400" from below List.

```
 const allStocks = [
      StockModel(name: "대주주", code: "000000", count: 10000000),
      StockModel(name: "삼성SDI", code: "A006400", count: 5000),
      StockModel(name: "성일하이텍", code: "A365340", count: 300),
      StockModel(name: "일진머티리얼즈", code: "A020150", count: 10),
      StockModel(name: "하이트진로", code: "A000080", count: 1),
    ];
```

this is my function.

```
void setStock(String query) {
    StockModel stockModel = allStocks.where((stock){
      final stockCode = stock.code;
      if(stockCode == query) {
        return stock;
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code field is unique across your objects, you can do:

```
void setStock(String query) {
   StockModel stockModel = allStocks.singleWhere((stock) => stock.code == query);
}
```

Comment: what is different firstWhere and singleWhere??

Comment: SingleWhere throws an error if there are more values that fulfill the requirement, ensuring that the key is unique

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like `

```dart
void setStock(String query) {
  StockModel stockModel = allStocks.firstWhere((s) => s.code == query);
}
```

To get multiple items

```dart
 final stockModels = allStocks
      .where(
        (element) => element.code == query,
      )
      .toList();
```

Comment: Also you can wrap with try catch or use `orElse` state on `firstWhere` if case it is missing the item

Comment: what is different firstWhere and singleWhere?

Comment: *firstWhere returns List's element* and  `singleWhere` Checks elements to see if test(element) returns true. If exactly one element satisfies test, that element is returned. If more than one matching element is found, throws StateError. More on [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/singleWhere.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get ALL item, use where, dart executable example:

```
class StockModel {
  String? name;
  String? code;
  int? count;

  StockModel({this.name, this.code, this.count});
}

List<StockModel> allStocks = [
  StockModel(name: "대주주", code: "000000", count: 10000000),
  StockModel(name: "삼성SDI", code: "A006400", count: 5000),
  StockModel(name: "성일하이텍", code: "A365340", count: 300),
  StockModel(name: "일진머티리얼즈", code: "A020150", count: 10),
  StockModel(name: "하이트진로", code: "A000080", count: 1),
];

void setStock(String query) {
  List<StockModel> stockModel = allStocks.where((stock) {
    print(stock.code);
    if (stock.code == query) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }).toList();

  print(stockModel.length.toString());
  print(stockModel[0].code.toString());
}

main() {
  setStock("A006400");
}
```

Comment: `    if (stock.code == query) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;` - please reduce that to just `return stock.code == query;` to avoid driving further editors insane. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I know that! I aggree with you, but for explaining how things work, and for better comprehension from the person who ask a question it is sometime better to be more verbious